# Installing two icons like two apk

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I created a simple app but am having trouble while installing the APK. The problem was I got two launcher icons (or shortcuts). What I'm doing wrong here

Comment: plz paste your manifest file

Comment: You've probably marked two of your activities as launcher activity. Post your manifest file.

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> remove this line from one activity in manifest file you not want to launch

Comment: ' <application android:label="Murakami" android:icon="@drawable/logo"></application>
  <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="Murakami">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</manifest>'

Answer (score 1):

All OK. I find problem

```
MainLauncher = true
```

In both activities.